# ExecuteScalar can return null?

Tags: .net, executescalar

I have a query : "Select IsNull(ItemBarcode,0) From Items where ItemID = 12313"
If in my database, 12312 ID does not exist on my table, then what will ".NET ExecuteScalar" return to me (If I assign it to an object variable?

```
    private Object Result = Command.ExecuteScalar(sql);
```

What will be result value?

Comment: Why don't you run it and see?

Answer (score 0):

From memory (unchecked), if it returns a row that has, in the first cell, a database null, then it will return `DBNull.Value`; if it doesn't return any rows, it will return `null`. If there are no rows, your `IsNull` doesn't apply, because that is applied to each of the zero rows returned, which is to say: not at all.

But as Jon notes: just run it. If it returns a `null`, then that fairly conclusively answers the question "ExecuteScalar can return null?"